# how to find value at or above 90% probability

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I would like to know given a lognormal distribution as per attached. How can I find the value x such that there is 90% probability that the a variable will be higher than x. May I know the coding in R to find the X value?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
> qlnorm(0.10,meanlog=0,sdlog=1)
[1] 0.2776062
```

Substitute your values into the `meanlog` and `sdlog` parameters as appropriate (note these are on the log scale). See also `?qlnorm`.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for your answer. Because I am new to R, may I know how to find the meanlog and sdlog in r? I have the data in r and fit a distribution, and found that the data follows a log-normal distribution. In that case, how can I obtain the meanlog and sdlog? Thank you very much.

Comment: Those would come out of however you fit your lognormal distribution to your data. If you use `MASS::fitdistr()`, you get an output with exactly those names (and standard errors). For example: `set.seed(1); MASS::fitdistr(rlnorm(1000,0,1),"log-normal")`.

Comment: Hi thank you Stephan for your answer:) Have a good day!

Comment: @Glen_b: that makes sense, thanks for pointing this out. Let me edit...